# Inject JavaScript to a link button from code behind in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, code-behind

Good day,

I have a repeater that contain link button. The value and number of link button is generate base on data pull from database. The HTML code is something as follow:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repCategories" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="<asp:Literal ID="litLink2" runat="server"></a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Here is some code that I try to do in my code behind,

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    RepeaterItem itm = repCategories.Items[i];
    GiftRow dr = tbl.GetRow(i);

    Literal litLink2 = (Literal)itm.FindControl("litLink2");
    litLink2.Text = dr.Name;

    string myScript = string.Empty;
    myScript = "\n<script type=\"text/javascript\" language=\"Javascript\" id=\"EventScriptBlock\">\n";
    myScript += "alert('hi');";
    myScript += "\n\n </script>";

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myKey", myScript, false);
}
```

By doing this, I will get alert `hi` when I load the page.What I want to do is, I only want it do alert `hi` when I click on the link button, instead of page load.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `LinkButton` and leverage the `ClientClick` event instead:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repCategories" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbMyLinkButton" runat="server" />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I'd also recommend you use `ItemDataBound` events of repeaters where possible:

```
   void repCategories_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {

      if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {
            ((LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("lbMyLinkButton")).OnClientClick = "alert('hi');";
      }
   }
```

NOTES:

- I wouldn't ever recommend you render javascript server-side unless absolutely necessary. I've provided an answer to fit in with the context of your question, but I would advise you have a javascript function already on your page and 'wire it up' server-side (if not bind it on the client with pure javascript)
- There is also an assumption here that you're binding data to the repeater (you should be anyway), which means you also have to wire up the `ItemDataBound` handler: `repCategories.OnItemDataBound += repCategories_ItemDataBound`

Comment: Hi DeeMac, Due to user requirement, I cant change the `<a></a>` link to `asp link button`. Further more, the my JavaScript is actually quite long, the `alert(hi)` is just demo example. Any other way I can do on the Literal element?

Comment: Using a literal instead of a linkbutton won't alter the size of your javascript. The fact you're handling a lengthy piece of javascript on the server is a problem. Get the javascript onto the client first, then bind it on the front-end.